# Indexes on table which has duplicate values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

1. Main table `PostInfo` columns like( `PostID`,`PostSubject`,`PostedDate`,`IsProcessed`).One entry for each Post ID
2. Transaction Table `Post_Transaction`

   ```
    PostID   PostComments     Post_InsertedOn               UserID
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    10000    VRDFHFGFTR     2013-10-26 21:08:19.817          43434
    10000    GFDGDFSDFF     2013-10-26 21:12:32.323          67576
    10000    HGFHGFBNBF     2013-10-26 21:43:43.545          3232
    10000    JNFNGHFGHG     2013-10-26 21:45:46.656          768
    10000    MJHJNGJHGH     2013-10-26 21:56:32.767          9897
    10001    XCVGFDGDFG     2013-10-26 22:54:54.868          3424
    10001    YTUGFGHHGF     2013-10-26 13:32:54.132          12313
    10001    HGFHFGHGHF     2013-10-26 18:08:32.878          6565
   ```

We have `clustered unique index` on `PostID` column in `PostInfo` table.

`Clustered non unique index` on `PostID` column in `Post_Transaction` table. How far this `non unique clustered index(Post_Transaction)` would work efficiently as there will be 50000+ entries for each `PostID` in `Post_Transaction` table.

`Or`

do i need to create an identity column(`IdentID`) in `Post_Transaction` table.so that i can create `Clustered unique index` on that `IdentID` column,`Non clustered non unique index` on `PostID` in `Post_Transaction` table.

Which way i need to proceed,Please suggest. :-)

Comment: Did you also declare the `FOREIGN KEY` relationship between the two tables?

Comment: Yes, declared relationship.

Comment: Adding an IDENTITY column on Post_Transaction will help you later. Choosing which index should be clustered is a decision based on queries running against this table.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an identity only to cluster on it **could** be a bad choice.

With a non unique clustered index, Sql will add an hidden uniquifier to each row (4 bytes), that's not a big problem. The choice of the cluster key is done according to queries on this table plus the fact that is should be ordered in order not to split too much and to be retrieved in ranges (identities or dates are often choosen) according to the application.
If you search frequently on PostInsertedOn it could be a good choice.
If queries are more ofen done on PostId it is better for it to be first.
I guess PostTransactions are often search by **PostId+PostInsertedOn**, that could be a good choice (non unique if PostInsertedOn can duplicate).

But the best way is to check that with the queries of your application and the query plans.

Also keep in mind that the cluster key will be an hidden part of all other indexes added as the lookup key of your table.

Comment: `PostInsertedOn` can also be duplicated.We dont have any combination which would gives us uniqueness.

Comment: I suspected that, but again a non unique cluster is not really a problem, sql add the hidden id for you ;) check the query plans of the queries of your application against your production database and do some tests, sometimes hard, takes time and resources with big tables

Comment: oups, a copy of the production database not the production one of course